# How to speed up wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I did wordpress for Restaurant. In that website is very slow speed for loading, its take 14.2 sec.  [Website Link Here](http://cityguidence.in/test/restaurant/).

I need to reduce that loading time, suggest me how to do this.(refer me if any plugin use to cure this problem )

Thank you for advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I improve the loading speed of this web portfolio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149545/how-can-i-improve-the-loading-speed-of-this-web-portfolio)

Comment: thank you for replay me @HareeshSivasubramanian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a lot you can do to improve the speed of your website. You can do some research on website performance optimization for WordPress. You will come across terms like minify, gzip compression, image optimizations etc.

A simple way is to use plugins that does these optimizations for you. There are quite a few good ones out there. But be careful not to add too many plugins as this will only increase the loading time.

I suggest [JCH Optimize](http://bit.ly/1GDTRRe) because they do pretty much every optimization needed for your website (less plugins to use), it's really easy to use and they have a free version that you can try. And they support other php cms like Joomla, Drupal and Magento.

[W3 Total Cach](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/)e is also good for caching. and they're are many other plugins you can look into.

Answer (score 0):

Sign up for cloudflare and setup yahoo smush it plugin for image optimization and w3 total cache to speed up your site.

Comment: Yes get W3 Total Cache plugin installed and you will notice a big change in speed.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is reading this in 2023, now there are dozen of plugins for caching and Optimizing JS and CSS to serve them through a separate cache file which acts as a separate layer over website to deliver website faster to end user.

WP Rocket is one of the famous plugins which can do almost everything except Image Optimization as suggested on Google PageSpeed Insights. For Image Optimization Imagify is the good plugin.

If you are looking for only Free Plugins to optimize website then here is the good article for [**Speed Optimization using Free WordPress Plugins**](https://www.yourtechnologyguide.com/web/web-performance/optimizing-a-wordpress-website-with-free-plugins/).